# Call ADF pipeline when certain set of files are placed

Tags: azure-functions, azure-pipelines, azure-eventgrid

I have a requirement to execute a pipeline when certain set of files are placed (which are date suffixed) in a location.

**For example below are the files:**

blobfolder1/a_20200101.txt

blobfolder1/b_20200101.txt

blobfolder1/c_20200101.txt

blobfolder1/d_20200101.txt

I have created a "Blob Created" azure subscription on the blob folder "blobfolder1". Whenever a file is placed in the location, it calls an azure function. Now this function checks if all the files (a, b, c and d) are present in the location with same date and triggers a pipeline.

This approach works if the files are placed one after the other. But, the problem with my current approach is that when all the files are placed at the same time, the function is called 4 times (as expected) but, the check within the function that all 4 files should be present in the location is true every time and the pipeline is called 4 times which is not what I want.

I want the pipeline to run only once.

Note: I can get the files with any date as suffix.

Can any one suggest how to fix this?

Comment: Hi, any update?

Answer (score 0):

> but, the check within the function that all 4 files should be present
>   in the location is true every time and the pipeline is called 4 times
>   which is not what I want.

Can you clarify the above sentence?

The basic principle of trigger function in ADF is integrated from azure function. For 'Blob Created', it is actually not about when the blob was created, what was created, or how many. It only focuses on one thing: Etag. Trigger will execute the pipeline for each new Etag. Even if you can upload blobs at the same time after trigger is enabled, the trigger will store the Etag in the built-in queue and then execute the pipeline in sequence. Each new Etag will let the pipeline execute once.

As mentioned above, I think it is impossible to execute only once, because you have four new different Etags.